# How to open link in Device browser when click on webview in xamarin forms iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a xamarin forms cross-plotform application,
I am using webview to load an external html page into it, Now we have an anchor tag in that html page, Here how to open that link in device browser when user clicks on it for both iOS and Android, i have write following block of code in AppDelegate.cs file for iOS but it is not working

```
 private bool HandleShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webview,NSUrlRequest request,UIWebViewNavigationType navtype)
    {
        if(navtype==UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);
            return false;
        }  
        return true;
    }
```

Please Help How to achieve it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can just use `Device.OpenUri()`

Comment: I am loading webview with external Html page, we have anchor tag in that html page, here when we click on on that anchor i need open it in browser not in app? is that possible with Device.OpenUri()

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: i am loading my webview like Loadfromweb.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = myurl}; can you pleas explain how i need to change here

Comment: replace `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);` with `Device.OpenUri(New Uri(request.Url));`

Comment: Thanks Jaxi, I did that one but again link opening in app only not in browser

Comment: In Appdelegate.cs i have

private bool HandleShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webview, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navtype)
        {
            if (navtype == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)
            {
               // UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);
                Device.OpenUri(new Uri(request.Url.ToString()));
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

And in my xaml page i have 

  Loadfromweb.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = myurl };

Comment: where i need to add Device.OpenUri(New Uri(request.Url)) this? in portable class library or in iOS project?

Comment: @srinivaschalla, please let us know, whether it helped you?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try to achieve this by using a `WebViewRenderer`. Create a WebView like `MyWebView` in forms and implement renderers on each platform.

### On iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace OpenUriDemo.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (NativeView != null)
            {
                ((UIWebView)NativeView).Delegate = new MyWebViewDelegate();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
    {
        public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
        {
            if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(request.Url);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

### On Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace OpenUriDemo.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        }
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            if (url != "Your First Request Url")
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                i.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(i);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Use `MyWebView` to load your url in Forms.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Device.OpenUri` and pass your URL.

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri(request.Url));
```

You can use `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl`, but you should create a new `NSUrl` object, passing in your URL.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(request.Url));
```

Comment: Thanks Balaraju for replying i am loading webview like mywebview.source=new UrlWebViewSource { Url=myurl}; i am getting anchor tag from that myurl into my webview, Can i use your block of code for that

Comment: where i need to add UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(request.Url)); this?

in portable class library or in iOS project?